# I am trying to modify my box plot

Tags: graphics

I have the following box plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Arm,Focal}
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=0.1036,
      lower quartile=0.1141,
      median=0.1301,
      upper quartile=0.2035,
      upper whisker=0.4313
    },
    ] coordinates {ArmAmpRemaining.csv};
     \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=0.2402,
      upper quartile=0.4032,
      lower quartile=0.1616,
      upper whisker=4.1380,
      lower whisker=0.1001
    },
    ] coordinates {FocalAmpRemaining.csv};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

I am trying to add the following additional points for "Arm" (`ArmAmpRemaining.csv`):

```
0,0.013180293
0,0.018654822
0,0.059293293
0,0.01712113
0,0.020415919
0,0.002116679
0,0.024196466
0,0.030270146
0,0.003312453
0,0.005664347
0,0.000423168
0,0.016275721
0,0.076458262
0,0.011121185
0,0.002557231
0,0.021957368
0,0.005987516
0,0.012759191
0,0.00235364
0,0.015715795
0,0.018448824
0,0.047329083
0,0.009960141
0,0.000900088
0,0.057903216
0,0.039836288
0,0.086832933
0,0.004415255
0,0.008460102
0,0.069336409
0,0.032064647
0,0.069953061
0,0.003605351
0,0.092048857
0,0.015318523
0,0.070592642
0,0.035856016
0,0.014697134
0,0.030244227
0,0.047442789
0,0.008148126
0,0.006431479
0,0.048919375
0,0.036452628
0,0.04012338
0,0.012237314
0,0.041330832
0,0.006483737
0,0.086826313
0,0.019028645
0,0.014778075
0,0.019564107
0,0.090206592
0,0.041855532
0,0.02772211
0,0.001268211
0,0.016971965
0,0.018543926
0,0.009281348
0,0.003170742
0,0.002008093
0,0.066902523
0,0.006594555
0,0.020020344
0,0.043824041
0,0.022989584
0,0.025013343
0,0.000741184
0,0.003801368
0,0.014534248
0,0.020886245
0,0.074713821
0,0.014659161
0,0.067094868
0,0.06916922
0,0.049128461
0,0.00224711
0,0.041028905
0,0.023492552
0,0.088936758
0,0.013947374
0,0.042410699
0,0.058028193
0,0.052355981
0,0.062576054
0,0.014741442
0,0.002988748
0,0.020011129
```

Similarly for Focal (`FocalAmpRemaining.csv`):

```
0,0.085550433
0,0.021287249
0,0.054641992
0,0.089767814
0,0.054300597
0,0.085360625
0,0.013180293
0,0.037799388
0,0.020739184
0,0.080429543
0,0.025299929
0,0.087961644
0,0.038837295
0,0.055432935
0,0.018654822
0,0.085538635
0,0.046548923
0,0.019007399
0,0.075910383
0,0.009710866
0,0.09294269
0,0.046695181
0,0.098408808
0,0.02654031
0,0.065928833
0,0.059293293
0,0.01712113
0,0.020415919
0,0.08186054
0,0.007369306
0,0.049673824
0,0.006224083
0,0.075212939
0,0.033084059
0,0.092996841
0,0.090102422
0,0.073958473
0,0.093766407
0,0.002116679
0,0.071691835
0,0.024196466
0,0.032544779
0,0.030270146
0,0.027683596
0,0.023143642
0,0.042322269
0,0.047166157
0,0.053851801
0,0.003312453
0,0.005664347
0,0.000423168
0,0.06610637
0,0.016275721
0,0.076458262
0,0.011121185
0,0.065921039
0,0.009776751
0,0.002557231
0,0.033379799
0,0.021957368
0,0.005987516
0,0.088669241
0,0.021519103
0,0.084979332
0,0.013585773
0,0.012759191
0,0.068397095
0,0.007899124
0,0.00235364
0,0.057863429
0,0.047545926
0,0.015715795
0,0.075272089
0,0.086902272
0,0.018448824
0,0.050769638
0,0.096159283
0,0.016819629
0,0.067519794
0,0.047725709
0,0.067942387
0,0.057542672
0,0.052908134
0,0.047329083
0,0.065360478
0,0.061350919
0,0.009960141
0,0.081348959
0,0.000900088
0,0.057903216
0,0.001928722
0,0.039836288
0,0.086832933
0,0.029412913
0,0.004415255
0,0.008460102
0,0.069336409
0,0.096641894
0,0.015396835
0,0.051885018
0,0.06118519
0,0.089504112
0,0.032064647
0,0.069953061
0,0.064568555
0,0.003605351
0,0.088598445
0,0.056245564
0,0.092048857
0,0.015318523
0,0.069664021
0,0.035951796
0,0.070592642
0,0.035856016
0,0.014697134
0,0.085998177
0,0.041507544
0,0.01402091
0,0.072040322
0,0.030244227
0,0.071699179
0,0.069420599
0,0.002815073
0,0.055009952
0,0.047442789
0,0.078520293
0,0.028536493
0,0.052940587
0,0.007882633
0,0.07580906
0,0.041393841
0,0.008148126
0,0.006431479
0,0.048919375
0,0.036452628
0,0.04012338
0,0.012237314
0,0.07907484
0,0.008461222
0,0.049268829
0,0.060536225
0,0.045610604
0,0.082517399
0,0.049608911
0,0.036472716
0,0.099066543
0,0.045945102
0,0.080169325
0,0.020654383
0,0.049130683
0,0.040526318
0,0.095743794
0,0.026422095
0,0.041330832
0,0.063104271
0,0.006483737
0,0.062140056
0,0.030844789
0,0.023401539
0,0.043798984
0,0.061601659
0,0.049490966
0,0.012323039
0,0.086826313
0,0.019028645
0,0.06160966
0,0.014778075
0,0.071077197
0,0.021983916
0,0.072999043
0,0.019564107
0,0.090206592
0,0.041855532
0,0.02772211
0,0.065877017
0,0.057188811
0,0.001268211
0,0.016971965
0,0.078502029
0,0.091118747
0,0.021846784
0,0.018543926
0,0.086796692
0,0.068826988
0,0.011705105
0,0.036299224
0,0.093116166
0,0.005116428
0,0.027833205
0,0.096625889
0,0.023425179
0,0.078619949
0,0.09336779
0,0.039122998
0,0.009281348
0,0.092557996
0,0.023579705
0,0.075467203
0,0.003170742
0,0.070494972
0,0.004068335
0,0.028013677
0,0.004590777
0,0.024894254
0,0.093571532
0,0.002008093
0,0.066902523
0,0.077024886
0,0.006594555
0,0.085060835
0,0.045240668
0,0.095727148
0,0.075107286
0,0.080514386
0,0.0575758
0,0.020020344
0,0.07362298
0,0.043824041
0,0.093785088
0,0.022989584
0,0.023220356
0,0.025013343
0,0.000741184
0,0.077797578
0,0.003801368
0,0.049083637
0,0.041199701
0,0.014534248
0,0.053193776
0,0.074713821
0,0.020886245
0,0.014659161
0,0.067094868
0,0.071375136
0,0.018604772
0,0.076710985
0,0.030768376
0,0.06916922
0,0.09365444
0,0.099069967
0,0.049128461
0,0.075625922
0,0.054247524
0,0.054459123
0,0.024679431
0,0.082286568
0,0.076042953
0,0.012189659
0,0.075097804
0,0.078496496
0,0.00224711
0,0.083666214
0,0.011158408
0,0.056916104
0,0.028883125
0,0.088824902
0,0.044909726
0,0.041028905
0,0.088936758
0,0.023492552
0,0.067377686
0,0.042743562
0,0.042442277
0,0.041327253
0,0.079577345
0,0.022377781
0,0.009780663
0,0.014759748
0,0.048864589
0,0.041382159
0,0.000318542
0,0.058058946
0,0.06808456
0,0.043493531
0,0.077937487
0,0.014574014
0,0.034914886
0,0.094631554
0,0.017146828
0,0.078749977
0,0.021339547
0,0.047544752
0,0.030539233
0,0.010218377
0,0.077065509
0,0.014030184
0,0.013947374
0,0.077556142
0,0.042410699
0,0.043024351
0,0.063273571
0,0.094216188
0,0.058028193
0,0.052355981
0,0.032126007
0,0.056048374
0,0.097246552
0,0.03730658
0,0.034912452
0,0.099210585
0,0.062576054
0,0.00853937
0,0.014741442
0,0.036697018
0,0.002988748
0,0.067353025
0,0.047356069
0,0.028381496
0,0.083497329
0,0.035051893
0,0.020011129
```

I am trying to call each `.csv` file within the `coordinates{}`, but it's not working. I am also trying to add two horizontal dashed lines at 1.5 and 0.1 with a dark green. I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback! Thank you!

EDIT:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1cm]
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[col sep=comma] {FocalAmp.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be you have to use `] table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {FocalAmpRemaining.csv};`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @HarishKumar Hi! Yes! :)

Comment: @HarishKumar Would you know a quick formula that creates a box plot and identifies outliers? Right now, I am using R and copying and pasting manual results, which is not that efficient... Thank you!

Comment: You need coordinates any how. How do you get them? Using R? What are you using R for? Box plot can be tweaked using `pgfplots`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Hi! I am using R because I am familiar with it, but not latex. I am still learning, and getting a better handle of pgfplots (e.g. plot histograms, curves). However, I have no clue on how to tweak it for box plots. Box plots are something that I use regularly for my research project.

Comment: @HarishKumar Can pgfplots compute outliers? Actually, I think I may have an idea...

Comment: Yes certainly...  See page 433 of pgfplots manual. and page 438 for `estimator`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Please see the edit, but got the error: Tex capacity exceed. I am using DNA segments.  I am looking for a fix. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Easiest is to use `laulatex` instead of `pdflatex` for compiling.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! I'll look into it! Can it work with sharelatex?

Comment: sharelatex must support it, I believe. Just check the list of compilers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coordinates {...}` expects a manual list of coordinates, not a file name. The `.csv` files can be loaded via `table[col sep=comma] {file.csv}`.

The dark green lines can be drawn with `\draw`. The coordinate, especially the `y` value is available by the coordinate system `axis cs:`, the left and right borders are available via the node `current axis`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}   
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Arm,Focal}
    ]

    % Horizontal dark green lines
    \draw[DarkGreen, dashed]
      (axis cs:0, 1.5) coordinate (tmp)
      (current axis.west |- tmp) -- (current axis.east |- tmp)
      (axis cs:0, 0.1) coordinate (tmp)
      (current axis.west |- tmp) -- (current axis.east |- tmp)
    ;

    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      lower whisker=0.1036, 
      lower quartile=0.1141,
      median=0.1301,
      upper quartile=0.2035,
      upper whisker=0.4313
    },
    ] table[col sep=comma] {ArmAmpRemaining.csv};
     \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=0.2402,
      upper quartile=0.4032,
      lower quartile=0.1616,
      upper whisker=4.1380,
      lower whisker=0.1001
    },
    ] table[col sep=comma] {FocalAmpRemaining.csv};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Package `pgfplots` can also automatically calculate the values for the box plots via `boxplot` instead of `boxplot prepared`. Also the average calculation can be enabled. Outliers are automatically identified and shown. The following example uses the same data (the remaining points as full data set instead) as the question except that it adds two points (0, 0.105) and (0, 0.11) to `ArmAmpRemaining.csv`. The example also prints the calculated values to the screen and log file. Special coordinate systems as `boxplot box cs:` or `boxplot whisker cs:` can be used to annotate the box plot, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) of `pgfplots` for details.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\newcommand*{\printboxplotdata}{%
  \pgfextra{%
    \typeout{Box plot values:}%
    \printboxplotvalue{lower whisker}%
    \printboxplotvalue{lower quartile}%
    \printboxplotvalue{median}%
    \printboxplotvalue{upper quartile}%
    \printboxplotvalue{upper whisker}%
    \printboxplotvalue{average}%
    \typeout{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\printboxplotvalue}[1]{%
  \typeout{* #1 = \boxplotvalue{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    xtick={1,2},
    xticklabels={Arm,Focal}
    ]

    \addplot+[
      boxplot={average=auto},
    ] table[col sep=comma] {ArmAmpRemaining.csv}
    \printboxplotdata
    ;

    \addplot+[
      boxplot={average=auto},
    ] table[col sep=comma] {FocalAmpRemaining.csv}
    \printboxplotdata
    ;

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result boxplot]

The calculates values are:

```
Box plot values:
* lower whisker = 4.23168e-4
* lower quartile = 9.4510461e-3
* median = 2.0015736e-2
* upper quartile = 4.7414362e-2
* upper whisker = 9.2048857e-2
* average = 3.1158e-2

Box plot values:
* lower whisker = 3.18542e-4
* lower quartile = 2.0696782e-2
* median = 4.6548923e-2
* upper quartile = 7.2519682e-2
* upper whisker = 9.9210585e-2
* average = 4.6918e-2
```

Comment: Would you know a quick formula that creates a box plot and identifies outliers? Right now, I am using R and copying and pasting manual results, which is not that efficient... Thank you!

Comment: @Johnathan Package `pgfplots` can already do pretty much including identifying outliers, see the extended answer.